# Accessing PHP array on separate script file?

Tags: php, html

I have this sample code but I am having trouble figuring out how to access the various array elements from a separate php script file called cart.php so that the fields from the code below are printed like a shopping cart before the user decides to confirm what they have selected with a continue checkout button.

```
<html lang="en">
 <head>
  <title>GreatBuy</title>
 </head>
 <body>
<?php
session_save_path('session');
session_start();
require_once 'login.php';

echo '<h1>GreatBuy</h1>';

//$_POST['username'] = 'abc1234';
//$_POST['password'] = '123456';

// get user's input
$username = $_POST['username'];
$password = $_POST['password'];

// check input
if (empty($username) || empty($password))
  die('<p>Error: Username or password is empty/missing!</p>');

// connect to MySQL server to check user account
$conn = new mysqli($hn, $user, $passwd, $db);
if ($conn->connect_error)
  die($conn->connect_error);

$hash = hash('ripemd128', $salt.$password);
$query = "SELECT * FROM greatbuy_users WHERE username = '$username' AND password = '$hash';";
$result = $conn->query($query);
if (!$result || $result->num_rows == 0) 
  die('<p>Error in username/password!</p>');

// get user's info and save it to session data
$user = $result->fetch_assoc();
$_SESSION['uid'] = $user['uid'];
echo '<p>User logged in!</p>';

$query = 'SELECT * FROM greatbuy_products ORDER BY cat, name;';
$results = $conn->query($query);
  if ($results) {
$number_of_products = $results->num_rows;
echo '<form method="post" action="GreatBuy_cart.php">
        <table border="1">';
echo '    <tr>
            <th>Product Name</th>
            <th>Category</th>
            <th>Price</th>
            <th>Manufacturer</th>
            <th>Quantity Available</th>
            <th>Quantity Selected</th>
            <th>Select</th>
          </tr>';
$n = $results->num_rows;
for ($i = 0; $i < $n; $i++)  {
  $product = $results->fetch_assoc();
  echo '  <tr>
            <input type="hidden" name="cart['.$product['pid'].'][pid]" value="'.$product['pid'].'">
            <td>'.$product['name'].'</td>
            <td>'.$product['cat'].'</td>
            <td>'.$product['price'].'</td>
            <td>'.$product['manufacturer'].'</td>
            <td>'.$product['quantity'].'</td>
            <td>
              <input type="number" name="cart['.$product['pid'].'][userquantity]" '.(empty($product['quantity'])?'disabled':'').'>
            </td>
            <td>
              <input type="checkbox" name="cart['.$product['pid'].'][checkout]" value="'.$product['pid'].'" '.(empty($product['quantity'])?'disabled':'').'>
            </td>
          </tr>';
}
echo '  </table>
        <input type="submit" value="Review Order">
      </form>';

}

?>
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Use session variables to save variables across different scripts.

Comment: You need to put `session_start();` at the beginning. It has to be done before you generate any output.

Comment: Do not roll your own password method. This `hash('ripemd128', $salt.$password)` is worse than PHP's `password_hash()`. Please stick to the recommended methods of password hashing